# Unable to explore tables as admin in apache superset

Tags: apache-superset

I've just installed apache superset following instructions at https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html. I then login to the web interface as admin. I also loaded sample data with 'superset load_examples'.

If i go to 'Sources > Tables' and click on any of the tables ('wb_health_population', for example) i get an error: 'This endpoint requires the datasource wb_health_population, database or `all_datasource_access` permission'.

I check permissions set for the admin role and existing permissions: 'all_datasource_access' is not enabled for the admin role, and does not exist in the list of existing permissions.

As i told, i just followed standard instalation instructions from superset's doc website. Any help on this? Thank you.

**EDIT**: Superset version is 0.20.6, python's 3.6.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `superset init` - this should initialize permissions.

See https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#superset-installation-and-initialization

(code-wise, `init` calls `security.sync_role_definitions()` which itself calls `create_custom_permissions()` which creates the said permissions)

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I've already executed 'superset init' at install time, so i'm not exactly sure what happened here. Thanks!

Comment: Might be an issue with sequencing of running `superset load_examples` vs. `superset init`

Answer (score 0):

I would also try `all_database_access` permission.